# Generating a random string to a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name=None, age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
    
 
def random_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

def main():
    foo = Person('foo', 'food', 10)
    bar = Person(['bar', 'car'], 'dar', 20)
    print(random_generator(10, "6793YUIO")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I76997Y37O
```

I want to add a random string to the first name of any object that has last_name value.
for example:
a random string will be added after the name 'foo' and another one bewtween the name 'bar' and 'car', and the result will be:

```
['foo', 'I76997Y37O']
['bar', 'OUO9UOUU3U', 'car']
```

How can I do it?

Thank you,

Matan.

Comment: Could you add a specific example of the output you would like?

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randrange
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name=None, age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        if(last_name!=None):
            try:
                for i in range(0,len(self.name)-1,2):
                    randStr = ""
                    for j in range(randrange(3,8)):
                        randStr = randStr + chr(97+randrange(0,26))
                    self.name.insert(i+1,randStr)
            except:
                randStr = ""
                for j in range(randrange(3,8)):
                    randStr = randStr + chr(97+randrange(0,26))
                self.name = self.name + " " + randStr

def main():
    foo = Person('foo', 'food', 10)
    bar = Person(['bar', 'car'], 'dar', 20)
    print(foo.name)
    print(bar.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think this will solve your problem, you can change the range of characters in both the j loops.

[Check this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLj2s.png)

Comment: Hey Harshith, if I print: `bar.name[1] = foo.name and then: bar.name[1], it gives me an error: Expected type {__ne__}, got 'None' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this.

```
import string
import random

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name=None, age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
    
    def insert(self, str):
        if self.last_name != None:
            if isinstance(self.name, list):
                self.name.insert(1, str)
            else:
                self.name = [self.name, str]
    
 
def random_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

def main():
    foo = Person('foo', 'food', 10)
    bar = Person(['bar', 'car'], 'dar', 20)
    foo.insert(random_generator(5))
    bar.insert(random_generator(5))
    print(foo.name)
    print(bar.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'VUZQR']
['bar', 'JWBAJ', 'car']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I want that all the first names will be in square brackets, how can I preform the code?

For example:

```
foo = Person(['foo'], None, 10)
bar = Person(['bar', 'car', 'zbabur'], 'dar', 20)
```

Second question:

If I want to equalize bar.name[1] to foo.name

```
 bar.name[1] = foo.name
 print(bar.name[1])
```

It gives me an error:
Expected type {**ne**}, got 'None' instead